# Batch info based on hour

Tags: excel

I am struggling to use a formula that would batch all my hours together. So basically I want to count all my data that belongs to 1pm, and then all the data that belongs to 2pm etc.

This is what my date column looks like.

```
06:39:38
06:40:08
06:40:39
06:42:11
```

I want to perform a count that would count all the occurrences for that hour. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a Pivot Table.

Comment: Yes - doesn't really help me if I am being honest. I only get 1s for each hour against each ID. I want to batch the data at the hour level, not at the hour, minute, second level.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the left two numbers are the hour (6AM), and you want to count the number of times you worked some time within 6AM. The simplest solution is to make a "helper" column that is =LEFT(A1,2), then drag/copy down. Then do a COUNTIF on that column: =COUNTIF(A1:A12,"06")

Answer (score 1):

Or you could create the pivot as ShNBI84 suggested, but apply it on an extra generated column (e. g. `B:B`) with `=hour(A1)` etc. in it. Make sure to select `Count()` and not `SUM()` in the pivot function:
[image]